# Suggestion required for optimization of word search requirement

Tags: java, algorithm, performance

I have written code for word search problem where we need to search and get the count of occurrences of particular word in N*N grid. I need some suggestion to improve this code, for better performance.

Words can be search horizontally, vertically and diagonally in both directions

code is :

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String size = sc.nextLine();
String finalArr[][] = new String[Integer.parseInt(size)][Integer.parseInt(size)];

int count = 0;
String diagonal1 = "", diagonal2 = "";

String arr[] = sc.nextLine().split(",");

// initializing array
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {

    String b[]= arr[i].split("#");
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {

        finalArr[i][j] = b[j];
    }

}

StringBuilder searchWord = new StringBuilder(sc.nextLine());
// Loop for horizontal and vertical count
for (int i = 0; i < finalArr.length; i++) {

    String horizontal = "";
    String vertical = "";

    for (int j = 0; j < finalArr.length; j++) 
    {           
        horizontal += finalArr[i][j];   
        vertical += finalArr[j][i];
    }

    if ( horizontal.contains(searchWord) ||
         horizontal.contains(searchWord.reverse() ) )
        count++;

    if ( vertical.contains(searchWord) ||
         vertical.contains(searchWord.reverse() ) )
        count++;
}

//loop for one diagonal count
for (int i = 0; i < finalArr.length; i++ ) {
        diagonal1 += finalArr[i][i];
}

//loop for another diagonal count
for ( int i = 0, j = finalArr[i].length - 1;
      i < finalArr.length;
      i++, j--) {

    diagonal2+= finalArr[i][j];
}

if ( diagonal1.contains(searchWord) ||
     diagonal1.contains(searchWord.reverse() ) )
    count++;

if ( diagonal2.contains(searchWord) ||
     diagonal2.contains(searchWord.reverse() ) )
    count++;

System.out.println(count);

sc.close();
```

I want to reduce number of loops. Apart from that can someone suggest me how to handle overlapping scenario. For example in 5*5 first row value is `ASKSA` and word to be search is `ASK`. In this case `K` is the overlapping character.

Comment: If you want to think about simpler code which is efficient at the same time you should get out of a habit of repeating code like in `new String[Integer.parseInt(size)][Integer.parseInt(size)]`; that’s not only longer code but also implying doing work twice. Similarly, don’t `reverse` the search word back and forth all time time in a loop. Just keep both forms in two strings, created before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit hard to read in some areas (generic/nondescript variable names, no commenting), but I see a few places for improvement. Just note that sometimes it's more important to write clear code rather than optimizing performance.

First of all, I don't think that your code works for all cases. For example, if the string `ASKASK` appears in a line, the count is incremented by one when there is 2 `ASK`s.

Secondly, you could probably add an optimization for palindromes, like `RACECAR`, whose reverse is the same word.

As it is currently written, the only loops you can get rid of are the diagonal ones. You would need to add `int j = finalArr[i]-1-i;` so you could move them both right underneath the

```
// Loop for horizontal and vertical count
for (int i = 0; i < finalArr.length; i++) {
```

That being said, you could rewrite the code a little to be more efficient. For example, in a 10x10 puzzle, if the word `EFFICIENT` is in a line, the letter `E` will be the first or second character. (You also know `T` will be the first or second character in a line that contains the reverse of `EFFICIENT`.)